# Query for SQL AND operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table contains multiple columns... in that one column Name called **Event** like below

[image]

In above image last column(Column Name: Event) I supposed to get two records for one event

Start date and end date of the event records.

```
string sql = "Select * From " + TableName+ " 
              where Date_Time in (
                (select Max(Date_Time) 
                FROM " + TableName + " 
                group by Event 
                having Event = 'Cooling'), 
                ( select Min(Date_Time) 
                FROM " + TableName + " 
                group by Event 
                having Event = 'Cooling')
            ) "
```

So I got two records of cooling event through above Query. Like that I need to get remaining events also in one query. How do I append other event condition in this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (And is this really a Windows OS related question?)

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: windows application with MSSQL server. Updated

Comment: "like that i need to get remaining events also in one query" - what are the "remaining events" in your sentence here? everything in the table? everything between those two times? (side note: it is *usually* a very bad idea to construct SQL by concatenation; I see that in this case it is the table-name rather than user data, which makes it *slightly less bad*, but: does the table name *really* change? that seems unusual)

Comment: event name changing like Cooling, Transfer, X, Y,Z. For that i need to take two records for one event.. see my query hope you understand.. sorry my English was bad

Comment: Please make an example output that you want from this data and add it to your question

Comment: almost answer gave in below by Venkataraman R.

Comment: I hope you're not getting that `TableName` from user input because it is wide open to SQL injection attacks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(    Select MyTable.event, MyTable.Date_Time From dbo.MyTable
    join 
        (select event, Max(Date_Time) as maxDate
        FROM dbo.MyTable
        group by Event)
            as t2
    
        on MyTable.Event = t2.event and MyTable.Date_Time = t2.maxDate
    
    UNION
    
    Select MyTable.event, MyTable.Date_Time From dbo.MyTable
    join               
        (select event, Min(Date_Time) as minDate
        FROM dbo.MyTable
        group by Event)
            as t2
        on MyTable.Event = t2.event and MyTable.Date_Time = t2.minDate
)
ORDER BY  MyTable.Event, MyTable.Date_Time
```

Comment: perfect but i need same order like first two records for one event next two records..

Comment: Use Order by event, date_time. I'll update the answer

Comment: @RajuRaj . . . This answer is not correct.  It is only comparing times and a non-extreme time for one event could match an extreme time for another.  It should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, you are right. I have corrected the answer.

Comment: @Raju Raj, Ok - I've put it back in.

Comment: @NeutralHandle if i get start Date(min Date) and End date(MaxDate) in one row.. my problem solved.. now start date already there i want to put end date in same row. so no need two rows then... waiting for replay

Answer (score 2):

You can use the analytical function `row_number` as follows:

```
select * from
(select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by event order by date_time) as rn_i,
       row_number() over (partition by event order by date_time desc) as rn_d
  from your_table t) t
 where 1 in (rn_i, rn_d)
```

Comment: @RajuRaj . . . This answer is correct and should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you want to get two records for events: cooling, transfer, corresponding to mindatetime, maxdatetime.

```sql
;WITH CTE_Event_Time AS
(
SELECT Event, max(Date_time) as maxDateTime, min(Date_Time) as minDateTime
FROM Table
GROUP BY Event 
)
SELECT * 
from Table as t
WHERE EXISTS (
SELECT 1 FROM CTE_Event_Time  as c
WHERE c.event = t.event and (c.maxDateTime = t.Date_time or c.minDateTime = t.Date_time)
)
```

Comment: Yes correct... not only two events may be 5 or 6 events can't guess

Comment: Working perfect but we don't know how many events like that.. check events and get records based on how many events.. Thanks for help we are very close to answer

Comment: @RajuRaj, I have removed the filter for event. Now, you will get for all events

Comment: @RajuRaj . . . This answer is correct and could be accepted, but I prefer the other one.